# Is $\frac{1}{z}$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Suppose I am to prove:

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$$ is analytic everywhere.

I see there is an obvious discontunuity at $z=0$, but **we can apply the residue theory, which means f(z) is indeed analytic**

$$ = \frac{1}{x + iy}$$

Using cauchy-riemann equations.

We must get it in the form:

$f(z) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y)$

$$f(z) = \frac{x - iy}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} - i \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2} = u(x,y) + iv(x, y)$$

then it must satisfy:

$du/dx = dv/dy$ and $du/dy = -dv/dx$ by these normal $d$ I actually mean $\partial$

Lets find $du/dx$

$du/dx = -(2 x^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^2 + 1/(x^2 + y^2)$

Lets find dv/dy$

$dv/dy = 2xy/(x^2 + y^2)^2$

This doesnt make sense: $du/dx \ne dv/dy$

But then how can we apply residue theory?

Thanks

Comment: Wait, how are you using "residue" theory to prove it is analytic? You can't use "residue theory" until you know it is analytic.

Comment: Since $u(x,y)=-v(y,x)$, I'm not sure how you got different values for $du/dx$ and $-dv/dy$. Looks like you computed $dv/dx$, since that's the only way to get a $x$ in the numerator.

Comment: f(z) is not analytic on a contour involving z=0. You can only make f(z) analytic by redefining the contour. You should check deformation of contours at singularities.

Comment: It is not analytic. Analytic functions are not allowed to have any poles, which $1/z$ has (at z=0). However it is meromorphic, meaning it has an isolated set (at most countably infinite) of poles and no essential singularities. Also: residue theory is based exactly on curve integrals around 0 at the function $1/z$. You should go back to your book.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, no I am trying to prove it is analytic so I can use residue theory AFTEr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've computed $dv/dx$, not $dv/dy$.

Comment: From the comment above,they say it is not analytic. then how are we allowed to use residue theory?

Comment: Okay, @ThomasAndrews, when I did, $dv/dy$ I got: the same except the first fraction was: $-(2y^2)....$ Why that?

Comment: $u(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$. $v(x,y)=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$. You should get $$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dy} = \frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$ You might get an initially different terms,but the values compute to the same. You did remember the $-$ in $v(x,y)$? Also, whn you say"I did..." please show what you actually got, don't make me guess what your result is based on some language.

Comment: And it *is* analytic on $\mathbb C\setminus 0$. Cauchy-Riemann is one way to prove it, but another way is to prove that $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x_0+h}-\frac{1}{x_9}}h = \frac{-1}{x_0^2}$$ for $x_0\neq 0$.

Comment: I apologize. I did not compute this manually, I fed it into Mathematica 10. Here it is from Mathematica:

$$du/dx = \frac{-2x^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} + \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$$

$$dv/dy = \frac{2y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} - \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$$

Comment: Write $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{x^2+y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ and do some arithmetic. That's the problem with using Mathematica - it doesn't actually help you if you can't do a little work.

Comment: I see,great answer. Accepted. I dont see one thing though. We just proved it is analytic on the WHOLE $\mathbb{C}$. But we know it is not at $z=0$, how to manage this?

Comment: No, we proved it is analytic where it is defined. It is not defined at $0$. Note that $\frac{du}{dx}$ is not defined at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: so can you tell me one thing? Cauchy-Riemann equations prove a function is analytic everywhere except where it is not defined? By definition of cauchy-riemann equations is this? Thanks

Comment: please? It is my last question?

Comment: It shows a function is analytic where is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider $$f(z) =  \frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{re^{i\theta}} = \frac{1}{r}\Big(\cos \theta - i\sin \theta\Big)$$

Spoiler:

> $$r u_r = - \frac{\cos \theta}{r} = v_{\theta} \ \ \text{and} \ \ u_{\theta} = -\frac{\sin \theta}{r} = - r v_r$$

Use Cauchy-Riemann equations to conclude that $f(z)$ is analytic at every nonzero point in the finite plane.

Comment: How do I conclude it is analytic at every non zero point? Using Cauchy-Riemann? I mean, how do I make specific I am not looking at $z= 0$?

Comment: Yes, looking at Cauchy-Riemann. Because you consider the function $f(z)$ for $z \neq 0$.Thus  $f$ is not defined at $z = 0$.